# What's th best way to mock a constructor for JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, mockito, powermock

I have an integrator class which I need to test, the class constructor instantiates a service client. As the service client is an external dependency, I want to test the individual responsibility of the integrator. The code looks like this.

```
public class Integrator {

    Client client;

    public Integrator() {
      client = new RemoteClient();
    }

    public String invokeClient() {
      ....
    }
}
```

What can be the best way to mock this ? Also, I need to make sure of the code coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Injection so you don't create the Client:

```
public Integrator(Client client) {
    //... argument checking omitted
    this.client = client;
}
```

Now your tests can create mock Clients which can be passed in directly.

You can still keep the no-arg constructor as well:

```
public Integrator() {
  this(new RemoteClient());
}
```

Comment: There is quite a tight coupling between Integrator and Client, because dependency inversion is already taken care at one level above.

Comment: There is no harm having multiple levels of dependency inversion.  Plus it sounds like you need slightly looser coupling so you can mock it.

Comment: I will describe the problem, the Integrator picks up a client by DI, now each individual client is tightly coupled to its service provider. The example shown is not appropriate, it is showing we are picking up a client where DI could be used, but as said, we are first picking up a client using DI and then picking up the service provider in a client which is tightly coupled. Now again a DI there, will force the integrator to chose a client and also specify specify the service provider which does not make sense.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It doesn't change the functionality of the `Integrator` class at all - it just gives you a way of mocking the client.  The new public constructor (with the `Client` argument) doesn't need to be called in production, other than by the no-arg constructor.

Comment: Yes, definitely that can be done. But even if I do that, the branch for the Default constructor cannot be covered. However yes, it will be testable.

Comment: I didn't get your exact problem even from additional comments but I also think this is correct answer. You could also play with PowerMock but I think it is weird to use this Powermock 'magic' for own classes